# how to use ngx-cron-job?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cron, capacitor

I am working on an ionic-angular project. and need to schedule some tasks. Can anyone tell me how to use ngx-cron-job here? can I use it with ionic? Is there any other option for scheduling the background task in ionic capacitor or angular?

Comment: Capacitor has a plugin for background tasks: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/background-task